# Are MATLAB's lsim outputs derivatives or the state vector?

Tags: matlab, simulation

I'm trying to do a simulation of a 2-body mass-spring-damper. I've set up a state-space model that I'm pretty confident in and set an input of a displacement and velocity at the base in just one degree of freedom. Upon getting my outputs, I expected that the output vector would just be the state vector at each time step. However, when plotting the output vector corresponding to displacement for each mass in the vertical direction (the input direction), it looked much more like a velocity (0 at the extrema of the input). The plots are shown below:

[image: Velocity plots?]

When I integrated the top 2 plots, I got the following:

[image: Position plots?]

Now, I obviously can just accept the outputs as they are and assume I am right in my understanding. But, I want to be sure. From the [documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lsim.html):

> lsim(___) also returns the time vector t used for simulation and the
>   state trajectories x (for state-space models only)

I'm just hoping to find out whether or not I am correct in that the output matrix columns correspond to the history of the state derivatives before I go base an analysis on a bad assumption.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My B-matrix expected [derivative, state,...] but I had them in the opposite order.